# How to use and set x and y to show image relative to bottom?

Tags: php, image, pdf, position, fpdf

I show some row data out of a database in a FPDF php file like this:

```
foreach($result as $row) {
    $dateD = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['Date'])); 
    $pdf->Cell(10,5,' ','LR',0,'L',0);   // empty cell with left,bottom, and right borders
    $pdf->SetFont('Times','',11);
    $pdf->Cell(31,5,$row['OD'],'LR',0,'C',0);
    $pdf->Cell(27,5,$dateD,'LR',0,'C',0);
    $pdf->Cell(18,5,' '.$row['Pack'],'LR',0,'C',0);
}

$pdf->Ln();
```

I would like to show just one image in a cell outside and just below the row data (from database).
However, the imagine keeps shifting because the total of rows shown differ.

I would like to show the image in a specific cell. However, the image stays in an absolute position.

```
$pdf->Image('img/im19.png',210,101,45);
```

Probably there are two ways to solve this:

1. show the image via setting x and y from the bottom (since the row data out of the database is shown above the image).
2. Get X an Get Y and do something clever with that.
3. Or could I use GetX and GetY to get the position of the cell I would like to show the image and then do something to show the image within these coordinates?

I could imagine setting an x and y for the image relative to the bottom instead of the top would be the most easy probably.
However, how exactly do we have to do this?

Answer (score 0):

from your code

```
$imageH = "img/".$row['imagepath'];
$pdf->Cell(60,28,$pdf->Image($imageH, $pdf->GetX()+5, $pdf->GetY()-4,45), 'LRT', 0, 'L', 0 );
```

my suggestion is just just make an empty cell and get the X and Y position right before it, after that write down the image

```
$startX=$pdf->GetX;$startY=$pdf->GetY;
$imageH = "img/".$row['imagepath'];
$pdf->Cell(60,28,'', 'LRT', 0, 'L', 0 );
$pdf->Image($imageH, $startX, $startY,-45,-45);
```

to adjust the position you can play with X Y and the  image size, you can  deal with -45 (I am not sure about this but I do that on my code)

Answer (score 0):

I experimented a little bit and managed to find out how to get this done.
Hope this could be helpful to others as well:

```
$imageH = "img/".$row['imagepath'];
$pdf->Cell(60,28,$pdf->Image($imageH, $pdf->GetX()+5, $pdf->GetY()-4,45), 'LRT', 0, 'L', 0 );
```

<sub>*Added on behalf of the OP*</sub>